# Automatic update of the date in the name of the table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
set @name_table= concat('NDC_FR_LOYALTY_','Fiat_', curdate()+0);

select @name_table;

drop table if exists NDC_FR_LOYALTY_Fiat_20181102_dec_orig;

create table NDC_FR_LOYALTY_Fiat_20181102_dec_orig as 

SELECT a.ID_PARTY, b.MD, concat(b.MD, ' ', b.Brand, ' ', date_format(curdate(),'%M %Y')) as Target, 
a.DESCR_PARTY_TYPE, a.OWNERSHIP_TYPE
```

> I want to change the date on the table in an automatic way. For ex: NDC_FR_LOYALTY_Fiat_20181102_nov_orig  to change into   NDC_FR_LOYALTY_Fiat_20181202_dec_orig.
>   can somebody help me ?

Comment: If you always are going to have only one table why not give it a fixed name like `NDC_FR_LOYALTY_Fiat_MONTHLY` (and instead delete its content every month)?

Comment: to this table every month are imported new data and that's why i need different name every month. and because of the request of the client we need the naming convention like this NDC_FR_LOYALTY_Fiat_20181102_nov ...but i dont wont to change it by hand, but automatically

Comment: And what's the logic for constructing the name?

Comment: it should be by default always 'NDC_FR_LOYALTY_Fiat' + (the date the table is created ) + (abbreviation of the month, the table is created) + 'orig' (as default)

Comment: So you can't be sure what the table was named last month since it depends on what day it was created. I guess you need to search some system table for it so you know what table to drop. Creating the name for the new table shouldn't be much of a problem.

Comment: never mind the drop table line..i dont use it often.. i just want to know how to create the name with date but to change it every month automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will get you the wanted filename based on todays date

```
select CONCAT('NDC_FR_LOYALTY_Fiat_', 
              DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%Y%m%d'), 
              '_', 
              LOWER(LEFT(date_format(now(), '%M'),3)), 
              '_orig')
```

Comment: can you tell me please where to put this select in the code above that i have sent here, so i can create the table ?

Comment: @DanjaMehmeti use it instead of the first line but with `SET @table_name = ` 
 instead of `SELECT`